# get rows with fixed difference of values between rows and decreasing consecutive date

Tags: php, mysql

Structure of my table : `ID(int)   |   NUMBER(int)  |  CREATED_AT(date)`

If I have three numbers : `10`, `11` and `9`, Can I get all rows from my table with same ratio of `NUMBER` values with decreasing consecutive `CREATED_AT` dates?

**Examples :**

***If my numbers are : 10,11,9 ... The rows may be :***

```
NUMBER | CREATED_AT
50     | 2012-03-18
51     | 2012-03-17
49     | 2012-03-16
```

Result must be "50"

***If my numbers are : 50,40,60 ... The rows may be :***

```
NUMBER | CREATED_AT
100    | 2012-02-20
90     | 2012-02-19
110    | 2012-02-18
```

Result must be "100"

...

I wasted a half of day for this, but I still have no Idea where to start...

*P.S : I have about 5 000 rows in my table.*

**UPDATE**

I did it with a bit of php code and a lot of mysql queries. Script execution time : ~6 seconds. [Tested on godaddy deluxe hosting] =)

Comment: There might be some way that I cannot think of, but the fact is that this kind of query is going to be ultra slow unless the database is restructured to make it more suitable to the problem at hand. What's actual issue you want to solve?

Comment: Can you clarify your question a little? In your example, are 50, 51, and 49 all `NUMBER` values or are they something else? Is it just a coincidence that the two examples follow the pattern: `a (date), a+1 (date-1), a-1 (date-2)` or is that pattern important for the data you need to select?

Comment: It will be easier to get all 5000 rows and manipulate it with php loop

Comment: @Joe Lencioni the date must always be (date), (date-1) and (date-2), but the numbers ca be different... for example If I will type 2,3,4 it can get : 40,41,42 or 10001,10002,10003... if I type 4,3,1 it can get : 50,49,47 ... yes it is important, but the numbers can be different.

Comment: Example: Your inputs a, b, c must be related with NUMBER column on table means |x - a| = |x - b| = |x - c|. and we must get the CREATED_AT value of this rows ? or CREATED_AT also should be date, date - 1, date - 2 ?

Comment: @safarov CREATED_AT should be date, date - 1 and date - 2

Comment: @safarov I want to get a number.. in your example it should be "a" but it must match to the pattern

Comment: @John: 1) Are dates unique? 2) Can you have more/less than 3 dates in a sequence? 3) If that is the case, what would the expected result be? Probably adding more data examples and an expected result (in table format) would help understanding this.

Comment: @Mosty Mostacho 1) Yes, 2) No, 3) First number. if i give 10,11,9 and it will find 40,41,39 I would like to have as result "40"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested it myself, but you can try this:

```
SELECT a.*,b.*,c.*
FROM table_name a
INNER JOIN table_name b 
ON b.NUMBER = a.NUMBER + $range1 and DATEDIFF(b.CREATED_AT, a.CREATED_AT) = 1
INNER JOIN table_name c 
ON c.NUMBER = b.NUMBER + $range2 and DATEDIFF(c.CREATED_AT, b.CREATED_AT) = 1
```

`$range1`, `$range2` are variables number1 - number2 and number2 - number3.

Comment: I have check on my test database its working. Probably u dont have any data in your table with your given pattern

Comment: I have tried with the existing numbers in table but it gives no rows, I will check it again.

Comment: $range1 = 76 and $range2 = -13. Did you try like this ?

Comment: almost like this.. i changed it a bit => if $range1 < 0 then it is a.NUMBER - $range1(positive) else a.NUMBER + $range1 and same for $range2

Answer (score 1):

In your example you have 10, 11 and 9. So, if t1.number = 10, then t2.number = t1.number + 1 and t3.number = t2.number - 2. This can be written into a query in this form -

```
SELECT t1.NUMBER
FROM (SELECT 50 AS `first`, 40 AS `second`, 60 AS `third`) AS  seq
INNER JOIN `table` t1
    ON `seq`.`first` <> t1.NUMBER
INNER JOIN `table` t2
    ON `seq`.`second` <> t2.NUMBER
    AND t1.CREATED_AT - INTERVAL 1 DAY = t2.CREATED_AT
    AND CAST(t1.NUMBER AS SIGNED) - CAST(t2.NUMBER AS SIGNED) = `seq`.`first` - `seq`.`second`
INNER JOIN `table` t3
    ON `seq`.`third` <> t3.NUMBER
    AND t2.CREATED_AT - INTERVAL 1 DAY = t3.CREATED_AT
    AND CAST(t2.NUMBER AS SIGNED) - CAST(t3.NUMBER AS SIGNED) = `seq`.`second` - `seq`.`third`;
```

**EDIT** - added the CAST to deal with negatives

This is not very efficient due to the join criteria but given such a small dataset it should be fine.